# Yocto Jethro: no package provider for gdbserver

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

I am using freescale.github.io freescale community BSP.

In local.conf, `MACHINE ?? = "wandboard"`, I have added `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "tools-debug"`

This will add gdb, gdbserver and some other tools to the rootfs.

```
SUMMARY = "Debugging tools"
LICENSE = "MIT"

inherit packagegroup

PR = "r3"

MTRACE = ""
MTRACE_libc-glibc = "libc-mtrace"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "\
    gdb \
    gdbserver \
    strace \
    ${MTRACE} \
    "
```

However, I got this error that bitbake cannot find PN gdbserver.

`Computing transaction...error: Can't install packagegroup-core-tools-debug-1.0-r3@all: no package provides gdbserver`

Is gdbserver removed from the bsp?  Why is it removed?  If not, where to locate gdbserver?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try rebuilding gdb, there's a very rare bug in the gdb makefiles that means it appears to sometimes not build gdbserver.  This will clean and force a rebuild:

```
bitbake gdb -cclean ; bitbake gdb -C unpack
```

Comment: I tried `cleanall` and `cleansstate` and still have the error.  `clean` solved it though.  Do you know why?

Comment: Considering that cleanall calls cleansstate and cleansstate calls clean, no.

Comment: Works! Was chasing a ghost error.

Answer (score -2):

In fact,

```
bitbake gdb -ccleanall  ;
bitbake gdb -C unpack
```

works;

I tried -c clean, but I got the same error no package provider for gdbserver.